# How to actively sync data between databases which are in 2 different servers?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I have a database ABC in server 1 and another database DEF in server 2. 
ABC & DEF both has SQL Server Authentication. 
I need to pull data from some tables in real time from ABC and store/update in DEF.
Both are in SQL Server 2012.
Is there any tool for doing this? Or any easy way to do this?

Comment: That's pretty generic question and depending on the details - you can handle it through some replication or linked server. Among other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this first of all you need to add the sever in sys.servers from where you want to sync to the destination server.

```
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='Servername'

    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'Servername', 'false', NULL, 'username', 'password@123'
```

After this you will be able to access the tables of sorurce server from destination server.
there is no tool that sql is providing. but you can export data from one server to other in sql server.